# Why does one 'if' layout work and the other not when they are simply reversed?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, vector, matrix, append

The following function has two vector inputs. It appends vector 2 below 1 to make matrix, if vectors have unequal length it adds zeros to the shortest. I've commented out the form that doesn't work, the form that does work is left in. Why does it only work this way round?

```
function mmat = makemat(vector1,vector2)

diffv = length(vector1)-length(vector2);

% if sign(diffv) 

%     addi = zeros(1,diffv);

%     vector2 = [vector2 addi];

% elseif sign(diffv)== -1

%     addi = zeros(1,abs(diffv));

%     vector1 = [vector1 addi];

if sign(diffv) == -1

    addi = zeros(1,abs(diffv));

    vector1 = [vector1 addi];

elseif sign(diffv)

    addi = zeros(1,diffv);

    vector2 = [vector2 addi];

else

end

mmat = [vector1;vector2];

end
```

Comment: It seems to work here. What problem do you find? Give an example with specific vectors

Comment: Okay so commenting the other half instead; inputting makemat(2:7,1:4) works fine, but inputting makemat(1:4,2:7) returns the error:Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not
consistent.
Error in makemat (line 22)
mmat = [vector1;vector2];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `if x`, with `x` any nonzero real number, evaluates to `true`. So `if -1` is the same as `if 1`. When `diffv` is negative, `if sign(diffv)` gives `true`,  and `addi` is wrongly computed as `addi = zeros(1,diffv)` where `diffv` is negative. This gives an empty `addi`, which is wrong.

In the other part of the code no error occurs because the negative case is correctly ruled out first (`if sign(diffv) == -1`). Even though the last `elseif sign(diffv)` should be `elseif sign(diffv)==1`, in this case it works as expected, because at that point the variable `diffv` can only be positive.

So: change all `if`/`elseif` conditions in your code to: `sign(diffv)==1` or `sign(diffv)==-1`

---

As a side note, you could define your function more easily as follows:

```
function mmat = makemat(vector1, vector2)

mmat = vector1;
mmat(2,1:length(vector2)) = vector2;
```

This works because Matlab automatically fills with zeros. In the last line the second index cannot be `:` in case `vector2` is shorter.

Comment: @user2839806 There is no need for the `==`if you know what will result: any nonzero real number (even negative) will behave as a 1. So `if 1` and `if -1` are the same (and both opposite to `if 0`)

Comment: I realise what you mean now, that in the incorrect version whether diffv is -/+1, the first 'if' part will execute, and so in the '-'case I specified the columns in zeros to be negative!

Comment: @user2839806 See also in my answer an easier way to code your function